# optional expression not grouped

Tags: regex

The regex I have is `.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+).*(Trident/\d\.\d)?.*`

The string to be matched:
`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)`

So I expect group 2 to contain the value Trident/5.0. But is coming up as null. Any clue what I am doing wrong here? If I remove the `?` after `(Trident/\d\.\d)`, it gets picked up as a group 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Problem

The problem is that there is `.*` in front of the optional `(Trident/\d\.\d)`. The regex engine will not try to check whether there is anything matching `(Trident/\d\.\d)` or not before giving up and match the optional group as empty string.

This trace will demonstrate how the regex engine works:

- After `.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+)` is matched, the remaining text is:

  ```
  ; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
  ```
- `.*` is greedy, so it will match everything to the end of the string. No text remaining.
- `(Trident/\d\.\d)?` is greedy, so it will try to match `Trident/\d\.\d` first, but failed. However, it can match the empty string (empty string can be everywhere, even at the end of line). So empty string is matched by this portion.
- `.*` will also match empty string, since we are at the end of the line.

Changing `.*` in the middle to lazy quantifier, i.e. `.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+).*?(Trident/\d\.\d)?.*` will not work for the same reason:

- After `.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+)` is matched, well, the same thing.
- `.*?` is lazy, so it will try empty string first. The remaining text is the same as above (nothing is consumed).
- `(Trident/\d\.\d)?` is greedy, again it tries for `(Trident/\d\.\d)` first, fails, and it goes for a match with empty string.
- `.*` matches the rest of the string, from where `.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+)` left off.

### The Solution

To force the engine to check for `(Trident/\d\.\d)` before taking the easy way out, we can make the whole `.*(Trident/\d\.\d)` optional. This will prompt the engine to check for all possibilities of matching `(Trident/\d\.\d)`, before giving up and be contented with empty string.

```
.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+)(.*(Trident/\d\.\d))?
```

Tracing the regex:

- `.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+)` same as above.
- `(.*(Trident/\d\.\d))?` is greedy, so it will try `.*(Trident/\d\.\d)` before going for empty string. If there is the pattern in the input string, it will definitely find the match. If there is not, `.*(Trident/\d\.\d)` will fail, and we resort to empty string.

If your engine supports non-capturing group:

```
.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+)(?:.*(Trident/\d\.\d))?
```

Since you only need `Trident...`, we have no need to capture the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

You actually nailed the issue . . . with the "removing the ?" . . . if the `(Trident/\d\.\d)` is optional, then `.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+).*(Trident/\d\.\d)?.*` is really no different than `.*MSIE (\d+\.\d+).*`.

The easiest was to address this would be to break it up into two searches: `MSIE (\d+\.\d+)` and `(Trident/\d\.\d)`.  There are more complex single matches that you could do, but for the sake of simplicity, you might want to go with two separate ones.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for one regex to capture both groups.